# How to stop displaying the data values from different data objects on Chart JS 2.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

I am using Chart JS 2.5 to visualize 2 data object in a bar chart and I can visualize the data values from both objects, but when I want to see the data values of one data object I still see all the data values of the second data object.

[image: Data objects]

Data object 2 is deselected but I can still see its values.

[image: Display only one data object]

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

**JS script**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
debugger;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["2 Jan", "9 Jan", "16 Jan", "23 Jan", "30 Jan", "6 Feb", "13 Feb"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Data object 1',
        data: [6, 87, 56, 15, 88, 60, 12],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#4082c4",
    },

    {
        label: 'Data object 2',
        data: [16, 57, 23, 60, 88, 40, 42],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#9082d4",
    }]
    },
     options: {
        "hover": {
        "animationDuration": 1
    },
    "animation": {
        "duration": 1,
                    "onComplete": function () {
                        var chartInstance = this.chart,
                            ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];                            
                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                    });
                });
            }
        },

    legend:{
        "display": true
       },
    tooltips: {
        "enabled": true
     },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
                display: false,
                gridLines: {
                display : false
            },
            ticks: {
                    display: false,
                beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                    display : false
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.js"</script>
```

**JS Fiddle**
[Edit online](https://jsfiddle.net/alex9007/4mxhogmd/14/)

**How can I see the data values for the selected data object instead of getting in display all the data values?**

This behaviour is present for the bar, line, polarArea, and radar graphs.

Comment: I am unable to see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to check whether a particular dataset is hidden or not, before drawing the text on animation complete.

To accomplish so, you can simply replace your `onComplete` function with the following ...

```
"onComplete": function() {
   var chartInstance = this.chart,
      ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

   ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
   ctx.textAlign = 'center';
   ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

   this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
      var isHidden = dataset._meta[0].hidden; //'hidden' property of dataset
      if (!isHidden) { //if dataset is not hidden
         var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
         meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.data[index];
            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
         });
      }
   });
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ["2 Jan", "9 Jan", "16 Jan", "23 Jan", "30 Jan", "6 Feb", "13 Feb"],
      datasets: [{
            label: 'Data object 1',
            data: [6, 87, 56, 15, 88, 60, 12],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "#4082c4",
         },
         {
            label: 'Data object 2',
            data: [16, 57, 23, 60, 88, 40, 42],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "#9082d4",
         }
      ]
   },
   options: {
      "hover": {
         "animationDuration": 1
      },
      "animation": {
         "duration": 1,
         "onComplete": function() {
            var chartInstance = this.chart,
               ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

            this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
               var isHidden = dataset._meta[0].hidden; //'hidden' property of dataset
               if (!isHidden) { //if dataset is not hidden
                  var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                  meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                     var data = dataset.data[index];
                     ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                  });
               }
            });
         }
      },
      legend: {
         "display": true
      },
      tooltips: {
         "enabled": true
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            gridLines: {
               display: false
            },
            ticks: {
               display: false,
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
               display: false
            },
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is the solution I was trying to achieve!

Comment: @grunt Many Thanks for your solution .. me and vishal try to fix this issue from last 3-4 hours ... so one again many thanks -:)